# How can I get the same color looking the same in different browsers?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, colors, cross-browser

I've picked out a color that I want to use throughout my website - it's the color of the logo and of the header, among other things. In my case, it's `#7ed321`. I've created the logo and exported it as a PNG with the color profile stripped.

Problem is, the page looks completely different in Firefox, Safari, and Chrome - each are rendering the colors their own way.

[image: chrome]

[image: safari]

[image: firefox]

*Chrome, Safari, and Firefox, from top to bottom. That's the logo and a piece of the header below. They might look the same on your screen, but they sure don't on mine.*

- **Chrome** - renders both header and logo as native `#7ed321` (sRGB `#94C9D6`).
- **Safari** - renders both header and logo as native `#54df16` (sRGB `#7ed321`), a much brighter green.
- **Firefox** - renders logo as native `#54df16` (sRGB `#7ED321`) and header as native `#7ed321` (sRGB `#94C9D6`). So the colors don't even match.

Basically, Chrome realizes if I asked for `#7ed321` in my PNG and my CSS, that I always want to see `#7ed321` on my screen, so it does the necessary conversion to sRGB to match my monitor's color profile.

Safari assumes I provided both values in sRGB, so it does no conversion to my target monitor.

Firefox does no conversion for my logo but does convert my CSS-provided `#7ed321` to sRGB `#94c9d6`.

As a result, the same page is looking inconsistent among browsers. The difference isn't significant, but I'd like to get them looking closer if I can. Is there anything I can do to my CSS/PNG to make the page look the same?

Comment: I saw a difference when the page was loading but once they finishes loading I put them side by side on Firefox and Chrome. I see no wild difference unless you mean like a different shade of green. But at least for me they looked the same?

Comment: Have you tried using RGBA in your CSS instead of HEX codes? i.e. background-color: rgba(126, 211, 33, 1);

Comment: TBH, you are battling the lesser battle, in that the slight colour difference between browsers for the above images, is minute compared to the huge difference you will get across tens of thousands of different monitors, with different settings, colour and tones, contrast, etc

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to ensure the logo and any other occurrences of the brand color in the code are the same. That is to use CSS to color any instance of the green.

Export the logo as just the white leaf with a transparent background. Then you can form the logo using CSS to create the circle and fill in the background color. For example:

HTML

```
<div class="logo"></div>
```

CSS

```
.logo {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px; 
  background: #7ed321 url(../img/logo.png) center no-repeat;
}
```

Now the code has applied the green color, so it will match any other green you apply with CSS such as the header.

As for making all browsers and screens look the same - that's a bit of a losing battle. Users all use different screens and the color will be rendered differently. It would quite honestly be pointless spending any time trying to do anything about that.

An alternative to using CSS to build the logo like this would be to show the logo as a font. You can do that will a tool like Fontastic which allows you to then do resizing and cool CSS transitions on the logo if you wanted: http://fontastic.me/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a vector version of the image you could use the svg format. With svg you can access the color hex codes for stokes and fills directly from the markup. But the problem probably has something to do with that some browsers can make use of your operating systems colour profile and others can't.

Answer (score 0):

It's an ancient and crappy solution, but sometimes the best way to make sure that at least the two elements match is to color the box created with css with a 1 pixel png that you export with all the same color settings as the logo.